# Does the wildcard (%) affect performance when you are not doing a partial search?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

If I am searching for the string `ABC123`.  Does it affect performance if I have

```
SELECT string FROM TABLE WHERE
string like `ABC123%`
```

A couple notes if this helps with the answer.  The longest the string will be is 6 characters.  There won't be anything like `ABC1231` or `ABC123B`

Comment: Is `string` indexed? Do you not have other patterns where you use `LIKE '%ABC123'` or `LIKE '%ABC123%'`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - The string is indexed and no that is the only pattern.

Comment: You shouldn't see any performance difference then. But you can always test it to find out!

Comment: @AaronBertrand - With the SQL Profiler?

Comment: You are correct, it does not make much difference.  If you put an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Sure, there are many ways to implement performance testing. Profiler adds more overhead than most, but it will be the same in both cases, so shouldn't affect the interpretation of the results - in other words if you use profiler you can compare two different approaches, but you shouldn't use it to try to measure absolute impact on a system with any accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `string` is indexed you shouldn't see any performance difference.

That said, you should always perform prudent performance testing in your environment, against your data, and with a realistic and concurrent workload rather than rely on what some guy on StackOverflow says.